# Asp:File Upload losses value inside update panel(mode=conditional) when below events has autopostvalue set to true?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, asp.net-4.0, image-upload

After i upload a image in "UploadImage" ctrl i clicked on below Radio Butons "rbtnDisplayDetails_Yes , rbtnDisplayDetails_No" the UPload ctrl losses value as soon as... also the page gets refreshed Why?
Give me a fix?
my .aspx page as follows:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"    TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" Namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" TagPrefix="FCKeditorV2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Cnt_Up_pnl_Publish_PDF" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSecurlyticsAdmin"
runat="Server">
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="smSecurlytics" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
<input id="inpHide1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Up_Pnl_PDF" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="error-message-container-new" id="divErrorMessage" runat="server" visible="false">
        </div>
        <div class="version-page-inner-divider">
            <div id="pnl_watermark" class="version-page-input-field-outer-container" runat="server">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                    Watermark Option
                </div>
                <div class="input-field-box-container">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnEnable_Watermark" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Enable" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnEnable_Watermark_CheckedChanged" GroupName="watermarkoption"
                        AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="Enable watermark in this Document"></asp:RadioButton>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnDisable_watermark" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Disable" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnDisable_watermark_CheckedChanged" GroupName="watermarkoption"
                        AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" ToolTip="Disable watermark in this Document">
                    </asp:RadioButton>
                </div>
                <div class="version-page-field-error-container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pnlPublishingOption" class="version-page-input-field-outer-container" runat="server"
                visible="false">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                    Image Option
                </div>
                <div class="input-field-box-container">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_Default_WaterMark" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Default" OnCheckedChanged="rbtWaterMarkImgOption_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        GroupName="watermark" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true"></asp:RadioButton>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_Upload_WaterMark" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Upload" OnCheckedChanged="rbtWaterMarkImgOption_SelectedIndexChanged" GroupName="watermark"
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:RadioButton>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_Text_WaterMark" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-50" Text="Text"
                        OnCheckedChanged="rbtWaterMarkImgOption_SelectedIndexChanged" GroupName="watermark"
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:RadioButton>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pnl_waterMarkImage" class="version-page-input-field-outer-container" runat="server"
                visible="false">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                    Image
                </div>
                <div class="input-field-box-container">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadImage" runat="server" CssClass="input-field-textbox"></asp:FileUpload>
                </div>
                <div class="version-page-field-error-container">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFileUpload" runat="server" ValidationGroup="PublishUser"
                        ErrorMessage="Plese Upload a File" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="UploadImage"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev_fuImage" runat="server" ValidationGroup="PublishUser"
                        ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-~ :\\])+(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.png|.PNG)$"
                        ErrorMessage="Invalid Image File" ControlToValidate="UploadImage"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </div>
                <div class="version-page-instruction">
                    <asp:Label ID="ImageType" runat="server" Text="Only [ .jpg  (or).gif  (or).png  ]"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pnl_WM_TextOption" class="version-page-input-field-outer-container" runat="server"
                visible="false">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                    Text Option
                </div>
                <div class="input-field-box-container">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtWMTextOption_static" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Static Text" OnCheckedChanged="rbtWMTextOption_static_CheckedChanged" GroupName="WM_Text"
                        AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True"></asp:RadioButton>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtWMTextOption_Dynamic" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-100"
                        Text="Dynamic Field" OnCheckedChanged="rbtWMTextOption_Dynamic_CheckedChanged"
                        GroupName="WM_Text" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:RadioButton>
                </div>
                <div class="version-page-field-error-container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pnl_waterMarkText" class="version-page-input-field-outer-container" runat="server"
                visible="false">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                    Text
                </div>
                <div class="input-field-box-container">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtwatermarkText" runat="server" SkinID="FormInputTextBox" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="version-page-field-error-container">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="PublishUser"
                        ErrorMessage="Watermark Text is Required" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtwatermarkText"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
                <div class="version-page-instruction">
                    Maximum of 20 Characters in length
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pnl_WM_dynamic_option" class="version-page-input-field-outer-container"
                runat="server" visible="false">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                    Text by
                </div>
                <div id="pnl_WN_dynamic_Text" class="input-field-box-container-1" runat="server">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="rbtWMTextOption_dynamic_title" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-100"
                        Checked="true" Text="ContentName" GroupName="static"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="rbtWMTextOption_dynamic_EID" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="EmailID" GroupName="static"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="rbtWMTextOption_dynamic_UName" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="UserName" GroupName="static"></asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pnl_WN_dynamic_Text_Display" class="version-page-input-field-outer-container"
                runat="server" visible="false">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                    Display
                </div>
                <div id="pnl_WN_dynamic_Text_Display_option" class="input-field-box-container-1"
                    runat="server">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="WM_dynamic_Text_Display_optionbyHeader" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Header" GroupName="static"></asp:RadioButton>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="WM_dynamic_Text_Display_optionbyFooter" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Footer" GroupName="static"></asp:RadioButton>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="WM_dynamic_Text_Display_optionbyCenter" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-80"
                        Text="Center" GroupName="static" Checked="True"></asp:RadioButton>
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server" Visible="true">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-outer-container">
                    <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                        Display Details in Virtual Console
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field-box-container">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnDisplayDetails_Yes" runat="server" GroupName="Details" Text="Yes"
                            CssClass="checkbox-80" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnDisplayDetails_Yes_Checked" />
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnDisplayDetails_No" runat="server" GroupName="Details" Text="No"
                            CssClass="checkbox-80" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnDisplayDetails_No_Checked" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlRemove" runat="server">
                <div class="version-page-input-field-outer-container">
                    <div class="version-page-input-field-text-container">
                        Display Remove Option in Virtual Console
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field-box-container">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnDisplayRemove_Yes" runat="server" GroupName="Remove" Text="Yes"
                            CssClass="checkbox-80" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnDisplayRemove_Yes_Checked" />
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnDisplayRemove_No" runat="server" GroupName="Remove" Text="No"
                            CssClass="checkbox-80" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnDisplayRemove_No_Checked" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreate" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div class="input-field-text-container">
</div>
<div class="input-field-outer-container">
    <div class="input-field-text-container">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field-box-container">
        <div class="button-bg-2">
            <div class="button-text-2">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCreate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="PublishUser" OnClick="btnCreate_Click"
                    CausesValidation="true">Publish</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-bg-2">
            <div class="button-text-2">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" PostBackUrl="~/Admin/Title/Titles.aspx" runat="server">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field-error-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By its default nature, a file upload loses the selection on every postback.  So since the page is posting back, it is naturally going to lose that value.

Also check this out: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/03/30/why-don-t-file-uploads-work-during-async-postbacks.aspx

Since i see the AJAX control toolkit reference, you could also consider using this: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AsyncFileUpload.ashx

Answer (score 0):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="SetSignature.aspx" method="post" id="frmFileUpload">
 <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fupSignature" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="SUBMIT"   style="margin-top:15px;" />
</form>
```

It worked on mine by just cover the fileupload control with a form and place the button whick take action based on the fileupload control inside the form as well. 
As you see, the fileupload control (which generated into html code with a form and a HTML's input type file), when implemented inside an update panel then if u fire an event such as button click outside the form, it's forced to a postback even if u're not placing any postback code in your source...

Regards,
Ken

Comment: Thanks @ken... but i gotta soln... also m gonna try this and give yo a reply! Thanks once again :)